# What is wrong with my sql statement or my php code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

i am having a problem with my SQL statement in the "insert record" and maybe some of the HTML code, if i did any wrong when i coded it, I have provided a connection to the MySQL and then looked up proper code for inserting records into columns. But doesn't seem to get any results from it.

Reg.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";

$username = "root";


$password = "redacted";

$db = "pre";

// Create connection

mysqli_connect("$servername","$username","$password","$db") or die(mysql_error());


// Check connection

mysqli_select_db("$db") or die(mysql_error());


  $fornamn = $_POST['fornamn'];

  $efternamn = $_POST['efternamn'];

  $kon = $_POST['kon'];

  $birthyear = $_POST['birthyear'];

  $smak = $_POST['smak'];

  $nationalitet = $_POST['nationalitet'];

  $epost = $_POST['epost'];
  $anv = $_POST['anv'];
  $losenord = $_POST['pass'];

$query = "insert into users(fornamn, efternamn, kon, birthyear, smak, nationalitet, epost, anv, pass)
 VALUES('$fornamn','$efternamn','$kon','$birthyear','$smak','$nationalitet','$epost','$anv','$losenord')";

mysqli_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

mysqli_close();

?>
```

I am having alot of problems with this, dont know whats wrong.

register.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Svenskaägg-Registrering</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Niconne'>

  <style>
.enk {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Niconne', cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.head {
  font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px
padding: 10px;
font-family: 'Niconne', cursive;
font-weight: 400;
color: black;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <body background="http://wallarthd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Egg-Colorful-Wallpaper-Free.jpg">
  <div class="head">
<h1>Registrering</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="enk">
  <form class="form" action="reg.php" method="post">
    <th>Förnamn: </th><input name="fornamn" type="text"><br>

    <th>Efternamn:</th><input name="efternamn" type="text"><br>
    <th>Kön:</th><select name="kon"><br>
      <option value="">Välj ditt kön</option>
      <option value="man">Man</option>
      <option value="kvinna">kvinna</option>
    </select><br>
  <br>
  <br>
      <th> födelseår:</th><select name="birthyear">
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>

        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2007">2008</option>

     <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="1999">1999</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
    <option value="1997">1997</option>
    <option value="1996">1996</option>
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1989">1989</option>
    <option value="1988">1988</option>
    <option value="1987">1987</option>
    <option value="1986">1986</option>
    <option value="1985">1985</option>
    <option value="1984">1984</option>
    <option value="1983">1983</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    <option value="1979">1979</option>
    <option value="1978">1978</option>
    <option value="1977">1977</option>
    <option value="1976">1976</option>
    <option value="1975">1975</option>
    <option value="1974">1974</option>
    <option value="1973">1973</option>
    <option value="1972">1972</option>
    <option value="1971">1971</option>
    <option value="1970">1970</option>
    <option value="1969">1969</option>
    <option value="1968">1968</option>
    <option value="1967">1967</option>
    <option value="1966">1966</option>
    <option value="1965">1965</option>
    <option value="1964">1964</option>
    <option value="1963">1963</option>
    <option value="1962">1962</option>
    <option value="1961">1961</option>
    <option value="1960">1960</option>
    <option value="1959">1959</option>
    <option value="1958">1958</option>
    <option value="1957">1957</option>
    <option value="1956">1956</option>
    <option value="1955">1955</option>
    <option value="1954">1954</option>
    <option value="1953">1953</option>
    <option value="1952">1952</option>
    <option value="1951">1951</option>
    <option value="1950">1950</option>
    <option value="1949">1949</option>
    <option value="1948">1948</option>
    <option value="1947">1947</option>
    <option value="1946">1946</option>
    <option value="1945">1945</option>
    <option value="1944">1944</option>
    <option value="1943">1943</option>
    <option value="1942">1942</option>
    <option value="1941">1941</option>
    <option value="1940">1940</option>
    <option value="1939">1939</option>
    <option value="1938">1938</option>
    <option value="1937">1937</option>
    <option value="1936">1936</option>
    <option value="1935">1935</option>
    <option value="1934">1934</option>
    <option value="1933">1933</option>
    <option value="1932">1932</option>
    <option value="1931">1931</option>
    <option value="1930">1930</option>
    <option value="1929">1929</option>
    <option value="1928">1928</option>
    <option value="1927">1927</option>
    <option value="1926">1926</option>
    <option value="1925">1925</option>
    <option value="1924">1924</option>
    <option value="1923">1923</option>
    <option value="1922">1922</option>
    <option value="1921">1921</option>
    <option value="1920">1920</option>
    <option value="1919">1919</option>
    <option value="1918">1918</option>
    <option value="1917">1917</option>
    <option value="1916">1916</option>
    <option value="1915">1915</option>
    <option value="1914">1914</option>
    <option value="1913">1913</option>
    <option value="1912">1912</option>
    <option value="1911">1911</option>
    <option value="1910">1910</option>
    <option value="1909">1909</option>
    <option value="1908">1908</option>
    <option value="1907">1907</option>
    <option value="1906">1906</option>
    <option value="1905">1905</option>
    <option value="1904">1904</option>
    <option value="1903">1903</option>
    <option value="1902">1902</option>
    <option value="1901">1901</option>
    <option value="1900">1900</option>
  </select><br>
  <br>
  <br>
    <th>Glassmak:</th><select name="smak">
      <option value=""> Välj en smak</option>
      <option value="jordgubb"> Jordgubb</option>
      <option value="chocklad"> chocklad</option>
      <option value="Vanilj">Vanilj</option>
    </select>
    <p>Nationalitet</p><select name="nationalitet">
<option value="">Välj land</option>
<option value="afghan">Afghan</option>
<option value="albanian">Albanian</option>
<option value="algerian">Algerian</option>
<option value="american">American</option>
<option value="andorran">Andorran</option>
<option value="angolan">Angolan</option>
<option value="antiguans">Antiguans</option>
<option value="argentinean">Argentinean</option>
<option value="armenian">Armenian</option>
<option value="australian">Australian</option>
<option value="austrian">Austrian</option>
<option value="azerbaijani">Azerbaijani</option>
<option value="bahamian">Bahamian</option>
<option value="bahraini">Bahraini</option>
<option value="bangladeshi">Bangladeshi</option>
<option value="barbadian">Barbadian</option>
<option value="barbudans">Barbudans</option>
<option value="batswana">Batswana</option>
<option value="belarusian">Belarusian</option>
<option value="belgian">Belgian</option>
<option value="belizean">Belizean</option>
<option value="beninese">Beninese</option>
<option value="bhutanese">Bhutanese</option>
<option value="bolivian">Bolivian</option>
<option value="bosnian">Bosnian</option>
<option value="brazilian">Brazilian</option>
<option value="british">British</option>
<option value="bruneian">Bruneian</option>
<option value="bulgarian">Bulgarian</option>
<option value="burkinabe">Burkinabe</option>
<option value="burmese">Burmese</option>
<option value="burundian">Burundian</option>
<option value="cambodian">Cambodian</option>
<option value="cameroonian">Cameroonian</option>
<option value="canadian">Canadian</option>
<option value="cape verdean">Cape Verdean</option>
<option value="central african">Central African</option>
<option value="chadian">Chadian</option>
<option value="chilean">Chilean</option>
<option value="chinese">Chinese</option>
<option value="colombian">Colombian</option>
<option value="comoran">Comoran</option>
<option value="congolese">Congolese</option>
<option value="costa rican">Costa Rican</option>
<option value="croatian">Croatian</option>
<option value="cuban">Cuban</option>
<option value="cypriot">Cypriot</option>
<option value="czech">Czech</option>
<option value="danish">Danish</option>
<option value="djibouti">Djibouti</option>
<option value="dominican">Dominican</option>
<option value="dutch">Dutch</option>
<option value="east timorese">East Timorese</option>
<option value="ecuadorean">Ecuadorean</option>
<option value="egyptian">Egyptian</option>
<option value="emirian">Emirian</option>
<option value="equatorial guinean">Equatorial Guinean</option>
<option value="eritrean">Eritrean</option>
<option value="estonian">Estonian</option>
<option value="ethiopian">Ethiopian</option>
<option value="fijian">Fijian</option>
<option value="filipino">Filipino</option>
<option value="finnish">Finnish</option>
<option value="french">French</option>
<option value="gabonese">Gabonese</option>
<option value="gambian">Gambian</option>
<option value="georgian">Georgian</option>
<option value="german">German</option>
<option value="ghanaian">Ghanaian</option>
<option value="greek">Greek</option>
<option value="grenadian">Grenadian</option>
<option value="guatemalan">Guatemalan</option>
<option value="guinea-bissauan">Guinea-Bissauan</option>
<option value="guinean">Guinean</option>
<option value="guyanese">Guyanese</option>
<option value="haitian">Haitian</option>
<option value="herzegovinian">Herzegovinian</option>
<option value="honduran">Honduran</option>
<option value="hungarian">Hungarian</option>
<option value="icelander">Icelander</option>
<option value="indian">Indian</option>
<option value="indonesian">Indonesian</option>
<option value="iranian">Iranian</option>
<option value="iraqi">Iraqi</option>
<option value="irish">Irish</option>
<option value="israeli">Israeli</option>
<option value="italian">Italian</option>
<option value="ivorian">Ivorian</option>
<option value="jamaican">Jamaican</option>
<option value="japanese">Japanese</option>
<option value="jordanian">Jordanian</option>
<option value="kazakhstani">Kazakhstani</option>
<option value="kenyan">Kenyan</option>
<option value="kittian and nevisian">Kittian and Nevisian</option>
<option value="kuwaiti">Kuwaiti</option>
<option value="kyrgyz">Kyrgyz</option>
<option value="laotian">Laotian</option>
<option value="latvian">Latvian</option>
<option value="lebanese">Lebanese</option>
<option value="liberian">Liberian</option>
<option value="libyan">Libyan</option>
<option value="liechtensteiner">Liechtensteiner</option>
<option value="lithuanian">Lithuanian</option>
<option value="luxembourger">Luxembourger</option>
<option value="macedonian">Macedonian</option>
<option value="malagasy">Malagasy</option>
<option value="malawian">Malawian</option>
<option value="malaysian">Malaysian</option>
<option value="maldivan">Maldivan</option>
<option value="malian">Malian</option>
<option value="maltese">Maltese</option>
<option value="marshallese">Marshallese</option>
<option value="mauritanian">Mauritanian</option>
<option value="mauritian">Mauritian</option>
<option value="mexican">Mexican</option>
<option value="micronesian">Micronesian</option>
<option value="moldovan">Moldovan</option>
<option value="monacan">Monacan</option>
<option value="mongolian">Mongolian</option>
<option value="moroccan">Moroccan</option>
<option value="mosotho">Mosotho</option>
<option value="motswana">Motswana</option>
<option value="mozambican">Mozambican</option>
<option value="namibian">Namibian</option>
<option value="nauruan">Nauruan</option>
<option value="nepalese">Nepalese</option>
<option value="new zealander">New Zealander</option>
<option value="ni-vanuatu">Ni-Vanuatu</option>
<option value="nicaraguan">Nicaraguan</option>
<option value="nigerien">Nigerien</option>
<option value="north korean">North Korean</option>
<option value="northern irish">Northern Irish</option>
<option value="norwegian">Norwegian</option>
<option value="omani">Omani</option>
<option value="pakistani">Pakistani</option>
<option value="palauan">Palauan</option>
<option value="panamanian">Panamanian</option>
<option value="papua new guinean">Papua New Guinean</option>
<option value="paraguayan">Paraguayan</option>
<option value="peruvian">Peruvian</option>
<option value="polish">Polish</option>
<option value="portuguese">Portuguese</option>
<option value="qatari">Qatari</option>
<option value="romanian">Romanian</option>
<option value="russian">Russian</option>
<option value="rwandan">Rwandan</option>
<option value="saint lucian">Saint Lucian</option>
<option value="salvadoran">Salvadoran</option>
<option value="samoan">Samoan</option>
<option value="san marinese">San Marinese</option>
<option value="sao tomean">Sao Tomean</option>
<option value="saudi">Saudi</option>
<option value="scottish">Scottish</option>
<option value="senegalese">Senegalese</option>
<option value="serbian">Serbian</option>
<option value="seychellois">Seychellois</option>
<option value="sierra leonean">Sierra Leonean</option>
<option value="singaporean">Singaporean</option>
<option value="slovakian">Slovakian</option>
<option value="slovenian">Slovenian</option>
<option value="solomon islander">Solomon Islander</option>
<option value="somali">Somali</option>
<option value="south african">South African</option>
<option value="south korean">South Korean</option>
<option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
<option value="sri lankan">Sri Lankan</option>
<option value="sudanese">Sudanese</option>
<option value="surinamer">Surinamer</option>
<option value="swazi">Swazi</option>
<option value="swedish">Swedish</option>
<option value="swiss">Swiss</option>
<option value="syrian">Syrian</option>
<option value="taiwanese">Taiwanese</option>
<option value="tajik">Tajik</option>
<option value="tanzanian">Tanzanian</option>
<option value="thai">Thai</option>
<option value="togolese">Togolese</option>
<option value="tongan">Tongan</option>
<option value="trinidadian or tobagonian">Trinidadian or Tobagonian</option>
<option value="tunisian">Tunisian</option>
<option value="turkish">Turkish</option>
<option value="tuvaluan">Tuvaluan</option>
<option value="ugandan">Ugandan</option>
<option value="ukrainian">Ukrainian</option>
<option value="uruguayan">Uruguayan</option>
<option value="uzbekistani">Uzbekistani</option>
<option value="venezuelan">Venezuelan</option>
<option value="vietnamese">Vietnamese</option>
<option value="welsh">Welsh</option>
<option value="yemenite">Yemenite</option>
<option value="zambian">Zambian</option>
<option value="zimbabwean">Zimbabwean</option>
</select>
<p>Epost</p><input name="epost" value="epost">
<p>Användarnamn</p><input name="anv">
<p>Lösenord</p><input type="password" name="pass"><br>
<input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone that can help me out, would be highly appreciated.

Regards - Zagros

Comment: Do you mean results as in return results or insert the record?

Comment: Insert the record, sorry for not being clearer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - There is error in your connection statement. You have define variable as string in `mysqli_connect`.

2 - You syntax for `mysqli_query` is incorrect. You need to store `mysqli_connection` into `$some` variable.

Syntax of Mysqli basic query: - `mysqli_query($connecton, $query)`

3 - You are mixing MySQLi and MySQL near `or die(mysql_error());`

Try

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "redacted";
$db = "pre";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$db) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

// Check connection
//mysqli_select_db("$db") or die(mysql_error());

  $fornamn = $_POST['fornamn'];
  $efternamn = $_POST['efternamn'];
  $kon = $_POST['kon'];
  $birthyear = $_POST['birthyear'];
  $smak = $_POST['smak'];
  $nationalitet = $_POST['nationalitet'];
  $epost = $_POST['epost'];
  $anv = $_POST['anv'];
  $losenord = $_POST['pass'];

$query = "INSERT INTO users(fornamn, efternamn, kon, birthyear, smak, nationalitet, epost, anv, pass)
 VALUES('$fornamn','$efternamn','$kon','$birthyear','$smak','$nationalitet','$epost','$anv','$losenord')";

mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

You need to learn more about [MySQLi](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp)

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. I appreciate youre help alot, and you are definitvly right i need to learn more. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @epidrollic Please accept my answer if you found it useful.